# Firebase local code not in sync with live project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am learning firebase, and I created the following example.  I created a Cloud Function by uncommenting out the example and I pushed it to live:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

This code was pushed to live and then confirmed by the firebase gui.  My issue is, when I invited another email to the project, ran firebase init from this email, and went through the brief setup instructions, the code was still commented out in the new local project.  What am I doing wrong here?  Is there some kind of firebase pull command where I can get the exact code from my project to local?

Answer (score 0):

Running `firebase init` does not **get** the existing code for a project. If you want to share the code with a collaborator, you'll have to use another tool for that, such as github or gitlab.